# Significato della locuzione "di stocco" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *La novella dell’apprendista esattore* di Beppe Fenoglio ho letto:

> Davide Cora si inquadrò tutto nella finestrella, ora spianava la doppietta al fitto della meliga, a dieci passi a sinistra di Aquino, il quale sparò **di stocco**. La pallottola carambolò su una sbarra della grata e si piantò nella fronte di Cora.

Non capisco il senso dell'espressione "di stocco" in questo brano. Me lo potreste spiegare? Ho cercato alle voci "stocco" di parecchi dizionari, incluso il *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* [qui](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000217.jpg) e [qui](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000218.jpg). Tuttavia, non sono riuscita a trovare nessun significato della locuzione "di stocco" che possa avere senso nel contesto del testo sopra citato.

Answer (score 1):

A mio avviso il significato (tra le pagine che hai linkato) è da ricercare in quello di *stoccata* :

> Colpo inferto di punta con lo stocco o altra arma bianca - in partic: nella scherma, colpo di punta in affondo inferto con rapidità e a braccio disteso.

È vero che l'espressione si usa per le armi bianche, ma si può utilizzare in altri contesti, prendo per esempio [dal vocabolario Treccani:](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stoccata/)

> c. estens. Nel gioco del calcio, stoccata in porta, il calciare il pallone, con un tiro forte e rapido, direttamente a rete

Penso quindi che qui si intenda che il personaggio ha sparato in modo rapido, probabilmente tendendo il braccio in avanti di scatto appena prima di premere il grilletto.